# Filter rows with only Zero values with 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

**Sample DF:**

```
ID   Name        Price     Amount      Fit_Test
1    Apple         10      15        Super_Fit
2    Apple         10      0          Super_Fit
3    Apple         10      0          Super_Fit
4    Orange        12      20          Not_Fit
5    Orange        12      0          Not_Fit
6    Banana        15      17          Medium_Fit
7    Banana        15      0         Medium_Fit
8    Pineapple     25      19          Medium_Fit
9    Pineapple     25      18          Medium_Fit
10   Cherry        30      56         Super_Fit
11   XXX           50      0          Medium_Fit
12   XXX           50      0          Medium_Fit
```

**Expected DF:**

```
    ID   Name        Price     Amount           Fit_Test
1    Apple         10           15              Super_Fit
2    Apple         10           0               Super_Fit
3    Apple         10           0               Super_Fit
4    Orange        12           20              Not_Fit

6    Banana        15           17              Medium_Fit

8    Pineapple     25           19              Medium_Fit
9    Pineapple     25           18              Medium_Fit
10   Cherry        30           56              Super_Fit
11   XXX           50            0          Medium_Fit
12   XXX           50             0          Medium_Fit
```

**Problem Statement:**

I want to `group-by` by `Name` and `Price` and then filter based on `Amount` with `Fit_Test` as conditional column.

1. If Fit_Test is `Super_Fit` then don't the no operation is needed. **(Rows 1,2,3 and 10 is same in Input and Expected DF)**
2. If within a `Name` and `Price` conditions and Fit_Test is not `Super_Fit`, check if it has a `Amount` as `0` then and only then remove that row **(ID 4,5,6,7 and in Expected 5 & 7 are deleted)**
3. If within a `Name` and `Price` conditions & Fit_Test is not `Super_Fit` if contract amount has values greater than zero then **don't** remove any rows **(Rows 8 & 9 is same in Input and Expected DF)**
4. If within a `Name` and `Price` conditions & Fit_Test is not `Super_Fit` if contract amount has all values equal to zero then **don't** remove any rows **(Rows 11 & 12 is same in Input and Expected DF)**

I can do solution where it removes all zero but no help with conditional column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain 2 conditions - compare `Fit_Test` and check if all `True`s per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) and for second compare for not equal:

```
m1 = df['Fit_Test'].eq('Super_Fit').groupby([df['Name'],df['Price']]).transform('all')
m2 = df['Amount'].ne(0)

df = df[m1 | m2]
print (df)
   ID       Name  Price  Amount    Fit_Test
0   1      Apple     10      15   Super_Fit
1   2      Apple     10       0   Super_Fit
2   3      Apple     10       0   Super_Fit
3   4     Orange     12      20     Not_Fit
5   6     Banana     15      17  Medium_Fit
7   8  Pineapple     25      19  Medium_Fit
8   9  Pineapple     25      18  Medium_Fit
9  10     Cherry     30      56   Super_Fit
```

Comment: It is not working I think because when I do `type(df['Amount'][0])` it is coming as `str`. Should I change this to float/numeric to work ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - How working if change `m2 = df['Amount'].ne(0)` to `m2 = df['Amount'].ne('0')` ?

Comment: Or use `df['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'])`

Comment: In `m2` if instead of not equal to zero, I have to compare and see the greatest value within a group...how will it change ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - do you think `m2 = df['Amount'].eq(df.groupby(['Name', 'Price'])['Amount'].transform('max'))` ?

Comment: I have updated the question little bit, can you please see

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - Use `m3 = df['Amount'].eq(0).groupby([df['Name'],df['Price']]).transform('all')
df = df[m1 | m2 | m3]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190372/discussion-between-rahul-agarwal-and-jezrael).

Comment: `m1 = df['Fit_Test'].eq('Super_Fit').groupby([df['Name'],df['Price']]).transform('sum'‌​‌​).gt(1)` and `df[m1|m2|m3]` not working..should there be any change in `df[]` line ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - You need count 2 and more `Super_Fit` per groups ?

Comment: No...value of `Fit_Test` doesnt matter anymore...just if for any combination Price is `15, 0, 0` then only `15` should be there whatever is the value of Fit_Test

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - So what is mask? can you join chat?